# rewriting url with mod_rewrite in .htaccess

Tags: php, html, url, mod-rewrite

hello i have a problem with my site.

i have a site where urls look like:

```
site.com/page.php
```

i heard that it is possible to rewrite the url like:

```
site.com/page
```

i was looking for that specific rewriterule but i couldnt find anything. all i was found is:

```
RewriteRule ^$ page.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?([0-9]*)/?$ page.php?index=$2 [L]
```

that does not work.

so if there is someone who could help me out i really would appreciate. thanks a lot.

Comment: FYI: A [simple cheatsheet](http://www.thejackol.com/htaccess-cheatsheet/) for `.htaccess`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this in your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Then in any of your urls, you can just do :

```
http://yoursite.com/about
```

Instead of :

```
http://yoursite.com/about.php
```

and it will still load

Comment: okay :) just another question: i have a page like below. because of multiple languages i would like to link an user to the site.com/english when he is entering for example site.com/spanish. thank you very much

Comment: see if this link would help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192135/language-redirect-with-mod-rewrite

Comment: not really because the problem is a little bit different to that in the link. example: i created the page 'english.php' that contains original content. now an user is entering not the original 'site.com/english' instead he is using the german word 'englisch' so that it is 'site.com/englisch'. but it has the same content on both pages. you get it?

Comment: yeah, i dont know how to help with that. Post a new question, I;m sure someone will know

Comment: okay, thanks again for helping me. have a nice day. regards from berlin, germany.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L]
```

And/OR don't forget to restart apache ;)