# RewriteCond redirect to a subfolder if language is Czech

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Our site currently redirects users if their browser language is Czech from our root domain to our Czech subdirectory as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+).mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (cs) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /cs/ [L,R=301]
```

However, for reasons I won't waste your time with, our login page goes from:
 **mydomain.com/cs/login** to **mydomain.com/dashboard** - we want a condition that redirects users to **mydomain.com/cs/dashboard** if their browser language is Czech (code: cs). Can you modify the above condition to do so? I'm not sure where the /'s go in these RewriteConds! Many thanks.

Comment: Hi - I think this link should help: [How to redirect based on Accept-Language with Apache / mod\_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661915/how-to-redirect-based-on-accept-language-with-apache-mod-rewrite).  Also take a look at [Redirecting according to browser language](http://tech-blog.borychowski.com/index.php/2009/03/htaccess/redirect-according-to-browser-language-mod-rewrite-and-http_accept_language/).  'Hope that helps!

Comment: That's not quite what we need to do. The user will already be at `mydomain.com/cs/login` and when logged in the page directs to `mydomain.com/dashboard`... but if the user's browser is in Czech I want them to be take to `mydomain.com/cs/dashboard` instead

Comment: This is more a question about how subdirectories should be written in a RewriteCond line rather than the language

Comment: Once the user is logged in all links, including the dashboard page, will be inside the `/cs/` directory. So the ONLY source is the login page at `mydomain.com/login` and `mydomain.com/cs/login` which forces the logged in page to be `mydomain.com/dashboard` - the idea is that any user with Czech as their browser language will be shown `mydomain.com/cs/dashboard` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in the .htaccess file for the public root directory:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.mydomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} cs [NC]
RewriteRule ^dashboard/?$ /cs/dashboard [R=permanent]
```

(If you're adding these directives to a httpd.conf file then add a forward-slash at the start of the RewriteRule pattern so it becomes `^/dashboard/?$`. I've assumed you're using .htaccess which does not need the forward-slash.)

This should redirect (with a 301 status code) a request for `/dashboard` or `/dashboard/` to `/cs/dashboard` if the string "cs" appears anywhere in the value of the HTTP Accept-Language header sent by the visitor's browser.

However, this may not be the best way to do content negotiation. For a start, your permanent redirect may confuse web crawlers into thinking that the /dashboard URL has permanently changed to /cs/dashboard and they won't realise that it's conditional. Secondly, if you're using a login script which is processed by a language such as PHP, it's probably easier to have that script detect the language and instruct the redirect once the user has completed login.

Comment: Thanks Arkanon. Yes this is in PHP using Wordpress but with a new plugins handling login and another the login redirect. All I need is for any user with a Czech browser heading to `mydomain.com/dashboard` to be redirected `mydomain.com/cs/dashboard` - once they are 'on the inside' all links are with /cs/ so that's fine. Right now our login page takes ALL users regardless of browser language to `mydomain.com/dashboard` - we want the Czechs to be directed to their language version. I hope that has made it clearer!

Comment: I believe the directives I suggest will do that, but let me know what's going wrong if that's not the case.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read it properly, that looks like it should work - at the moment this test site is in a directory called `mydomain.com/new` - can you amend the code to work for this directory? Thanks!

Comment: If the structure remains the same, but hidden inside the /new/ sub-directory, then you should just need to change the RewriteRule so that it becomes `RewriteRule ^new/dashboard/?$ /new/cs/dashboard [R=permanent]`. (Ideally you should be testing on a test rig which is a separate machine configured identically to the live machine.)

Comment: Hmmm, I'm still able to access `mydomain.com/new/dashboard` despite have the browser's language as Czech :S The suggested directives are in .htaccess in root

Comment: Just to make sure the language setting is as expected, can you tell us what you see for your Accept-Language value if you visit [xhaus HTTP header checker](http://www.xhaus.com/headers) with your test browser?

Comment: Strange. I can't see anything wrong, so it should work. It's nearly midnight here, but I'll aim to install Apache tomorrow and find out what's going on. I've also tagged your question with the **.htaccess** tag to see if it lures more people into the fray in the meantime.

Comment: I tried it with a completely 'fresh' .htaccess in the root directory too, no change.

Comment: FYI: I tried the same but referencing a directory while in the root directory itself - I'm thinking the issue may be our beta site is in directory `mydomain.com/new/` at the moment and not recognising the htaccess rule?

I tried this and it worked perfectly while linking to it from the root:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+).mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (cs) [NC]
RewriteRule ^dashboard/?$ /cs/dashboard/ [R=permanent]`

Comment: And yet when pointing it to `/new/dashboard` to redirect to `/new/cs/dashboard` the page stays on `/new/dashboard` ...arrrgh

Comment: Okay, this was driving me mad too for the last ten minutes but I think I've worked it out. The three directives I've given in my answer do work fine (and I've tested with the 'new' variant for testing, and that works fine). However, the browser I'm using, Firefox 20, seems to be caching the result of the redirect and then using the cache for future refreshes. So even if you change the language your browser sends with Accept-Language, the browser just shows you the URL it cached before. But if you clear your cache each time you change the language settings, it seems to work fine.

Comment: The only language I have installed on there is Czech. So that is odd. For now I've taken the easy way out and installed a 'choose your language' button on the site when the user is logged in. It's a cop out really.

Comment: If it is just a cache issue, then your visitors won't have a problem because they won't be changing their language settings often (or ever). It's just a nuisance for testing. Probably easiest to use two different browsers, say Firefox for Czech testing and Opera or Konqueror for non-Czech testing.

Comment: I'm doing that - Chrome in English and Internet Explorer in Czech.

Comment: And it's still not working? That's weird. Once I worked out the cache was a problem, and cleared it each time, the rules above did the redirect exactly as required.

Comment: This works if I go directly to `mydomain.com/new/dashboard`, redirects to `mydomain.com/new/cs/dashboard` but if I use the login page it simply shows `mydomain.com/new/dashboard`. Wondering if this is a Wordpress issue. Or, something is not letting our special language rule take precedent over other behaviour.

Comment: I put the redirect code above the wordpress htaccess code... still no joy

Comment: Something is definitely interfering. If you're able to modify the login script, put logic in there to check for Accept-Language and redirect the user appropriately once they're login is validated. Beyond that I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help Arkanon. I'll keep persevering and will update this if success comes within .htaccess - in the meantime I have a big old 'select your language' button as a fall-back.